# return data in from django queryset in the a specified format below

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a database table with a field named groupname.
I have a queryset that counts the number of groupname as follows

```
count_groups=Eventgroup.objects.values('groupname').annotate(group_count=Count('groupname'))
```

I want to return this values in the following format:

```
[{
    data : [[0, 4]],
    label : "Event 2345"
}, {
    data : [[0, 3]],
    label : "Event 34567"
}, {
    data : [[0, 5]],
    label : "Event 4567",

}, {
    data : [[0, 3]],
    label : "Event 4356"
}];
```

where label should be the name of the groupname, in data,the `0` is always there but the second value is the count of the groupname.
here is my model:

```
class Eventgroup(models.Model):
    event_id=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    OS_CHOICE=(('Win 2003','windows 2003'),
        ('Win 2008','Windows 2008'),
        ('Win XP','Windows XP'),
        ('Win VISTA','Win VISTA'),
        ('Win 2007','Windows 2007'),
        )
    windows=models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=OS_CHOICE,default='Win 2003')
    groupname=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return " %s, group name:%s" \
            % (int(self.event_id), str(self.groupname.name),str(self.windows.name))
    class Meta:
        db_table= 'Eventgroups'
        verbose_name_plural='eventgroups'
```

please give insights based on my data. regards

Comment: How it's possible to have 1.03 or 3.5 counts of groupname? It should be an integer. Please post your model.

Comment: Hi Fasouto, those are just arbitary values, yeah they are integer values

Comment: Hi Fasouto, i made some edits and added in my model definition

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
def format_results(queryset):
    for eventgroup in queryset:
        yield {
            'data': [[0, eventgroup['group_count']]],
            'label': eventgroup['name'],
        }

count_groups = Eventgroup.objects.values('groupname').annotate(group_count=Count('groupname'))
results = format_results(count_groups)
```

Using a generator like this behaves similarly to a queryset in that it is not immediately evaluated or fully loaded into memory as a list object.

Comment: Hi, Anentropic, when i do this i get <generator object format_results at 0x03305508>;
as result

Comment: That's right, you can iterate over that object in a for loop or pass it to list constructor to evaluate it, same as with a queryset

Comment: pass it to a list constructor? hope you wont mind showing that,thanks

Comment: iterate: `for row in results:` ... To a list: `list(results) ` passing to list constructor in this way will iterate over the whole queryset and load into memory, the same as if you do `list(queryset)`… don't do this unless you really need to

Comment: Thank you, i did to list early and got this error 'dict' object has no attribute 'group_count'

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I forgot you have a `values` queryset here which returns dicts instead of model instances. I will update my answer

Comment: Thanks a punch Anentropic